# Apps unavailable after upgrade to Gingerbread

Tags: applications, 2.3-gingerbread, updates, sd-card, htc-droid-incredible

I recently upgraded my HTC Incredible from Froyo to Gingerbread. Everything seems to work fine, except for several apps that had their home screen icons revert to the default Android icon and clicking them does nothing. I believe they are all the apps I had on my SD card before the OS upgrade. If I go to Settings -> Applications and look at the "On SD card" tab, the apps are listed, but if I try to "Move to phone" I get the error:

> Failed to move application. The application does not exist.

In Market, the apps are listed as purchased but not installed. What do I need to do to get my apps back?

**Edit:** It looks like this is related to the out of memory bugs in the new 2.3 update (see [my related question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15666/low-on-space-warning-with-over-50-free)). At one point after trying to clear memory the apps came back, but then I got the memory warnings again and they disappeared again.

Comment: Did you try to install them again?

Answer (score 2):

I deleted all the apps that couldn't be found. Then you can just install them again, like onik suggested.  Apps that you purchased are linked to your account, so the market keeps track of them, even after deleting them. Purchases that you delete will be organized in the Not Installed section of your My Apps list.