# Low Memory issues on Droid Incredible after upgrade to Android 2.3.4

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, htc-droid-incredible

Since upgrading to Gingerbread, my phone is constantly getting low memory notifications despite having plenty of room. It is causing a number of my applications to fail. I have tried clearing memory but the low memory issue just comes back after a few hours.

Anyone seeing the same behavior? Is there any resolution outside of the standard VW "reformat the phone" solution?

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate of this: [“Low on space” warning with over 50% free](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15666/low-on-space-warning-with-over-50-free) (which was itself closed as a duplicate, though same device in this instance).

Comment: That shouldn't have been marked as a dupe as it is a different device and OS version. This is clearly a faulty upgrade. The other could just be high memory usage.

Comment: @smp7d: See the edit I made to my question.