# Google Play insufficient space error

Tags: applications, internal-storage, installation, insufficient-memory, system-error

I am using [RED MI Note](http://www.gsmarena.com/xiaomi_redmi-5609.php).

All my applications are installed in internal storage.

I have 2GB of space available in `internal` device.

But when i try to install [Any.do](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anydo&hl=en) and [Greenify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.greenify&hl=en) I am getting error that

```
"Not Enough Space Available"
```

> I tried Many ways:
>
> 1. Uninstall lots of apps (Cleared almost 1 GB)
> 2. Uninstalled Play Store and Re-installed
> 3. Cleared Cache of Play Services.
> 4. Uninstalled Play Services.
> 5. Cleared Data of Play Store.
> 6. Install older version of play store.
> 7. Cleared App cache of all apps.
> 8. Downloaded apk and then installed (not worked)
>
> 9.Installed older version of apps that work earlier (not worked)

I am searching for this solution from several days. I tried almost every Possible solution on net.

I am asking it here so that i can get the solution.

**NOTE** I even tried complete factory reset. But It also doesn't work

Comment: **NOTE** I even tried complete factory reset. But It also doesn;' work

Comment: I assume you've already checked with our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) – and tried above after a factory-reset *without* installing anything else before. There was a similar issue here before (see: [False “low on space” (internal storage) warning on HTC Incredible](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/21300/16575)), culprit was never found (to my knowledge at least). Last resort: contact manufacturer, see if they have a firmware upgrade or replace the board (might be faulty chips giving wrong reports).

Comment: yes thats the only way i can resolve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether this works for some one or not.

I installed [Lucky Patcher](https://www.luckypatchers.com/download/) in my Phone.

And immediately it showed me warning that

```
 unused file Anydo.odex
```

and after then I Am able to install all these applications.
Its weird.

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem on my Galaxy S Advance. I have 0.5GB remaining, but apps won't install.
I have very less reputation, hence I can't comment.
You may try the treatment by the Clean Master app, though I doubt its effectiveness in solving your (OUR) problem.

Comment: it can't solve..I tried it...

Comment: Did Clean Master solved Your problem ?

Comment: I don't know. I remember now, that my problem was that I could not update to the latest version of firefox because of insufficient space. I could not update Firefox, after using Clean Master. But I was able to install some other smaller apps. After 2 days, I uninstalled 1 or 2 apps, then Firefox was able to update.. so there's a lot of confusion. I did not conduct an experiment scientifically.. BTW, you username, Dalvik is cool, with reference to Android ( I hope you know what I mean).

Comment: yaa i knw that...their is story behind the name...btw me name is RAHUL

Comment: Do you use Google Music? Try going into the Music app's settings and clearing all the cached songs. I had a similar issue and this fixed it for me since I had a couple of GBs of songs cached.

Comment: @Hassaan I dont use google music app..and I also used and run app cache cleaner... I also done factory reset..but this also can't help me out

Comment: @IshaanDube Dalvik already wrote not even a factory-reset solved the issue (comment on the question, before you answered). So I doubt any "cleaning app" would. From context and experience, I rather suspect an OS or hardware error (some API/chip reports wrong values), which would be for the manufacturer to solve (board replacement, ROM upgrade).