# insufficient space although of available space!

Tags: internal-storage, insufficient-memory

My tablet shows "insufficient space" error message whenever I install new apps (Clean Master) although it has enough storage!

- Default write disk: phone storage
- Internal storage 3.87GB: available 385MB
- Phone storage 27.73GB: available 18.80GB
- Android 5.1

Note: I tried to fix this issue by using SD Card and set "Default write disk" to it but it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Have you already checked with our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info)? This sounds a bit like the (admittedly a bit older) [False “low on space” (internal storage) warning on HTC Incredible](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/21300/16575).

Comment: @Izzy The wiki page doesn't contain on similar problem because my tablet has a free space while I get error message of insufficient space

Comment: I got that. Have you seen the second link to ***FALSE** low on space warning?* That link was taken from exactly that wiki page :) Have you checked with that post?

Comment: Please see this new article 2017/02/10 [10 most useless apps and games for Android](http://www.androidauthority.com/most-useless-apps-android-749163). Most prominent, but specifically named in the list: Clean Master (along with quote-Booster apps, Anti-Virus apps, and Task Killers-unquote)