# Why does HTC Incredible not update?

Tags: htc-droid-incredible, verizon, ota-update

My HTC Incredible (Verizon) has tried to update to <strike>either Ice Cream Sandwich (android 4.0.x) or just</strike> build # 4.x <strike>(I'm not sure which)</strike> for the past two weeks or so.  Either way, it has not been succesful.

Sometimes I'll get a notification telling me that the update has been downloaded, and asks me whether I wan't to reboot to install.  I tried that a bunch of times, but neither time did it even shut down after the ten second delay/grace period.  Once I tried going to Settings > About Phone > System updates, and downloaded the update and tried to install, but the same thing happened: ten second countdown, then nothing.

Now, the notification never pops up, and Settings > About Phone > System updates indicates that no new updates are out.  What's happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had this problem with previous OTA updates on my HTC.  The problem I ran into is that my phone didn't have enough "space" for the update to actually install gracefully.  The bigger problem is that there are many different places the phone can run out of "space".  I ended up booting into the recovery to wipe the cache partition (for some details see ["Low on space" warning with over 50% free](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15666/low-on-space-warning-with-over-50-free)).  I also ended up wiping the app cache *and data* on a number of apps (including the launcher -- lost all my icons, gmail, maps, etc) to reduce "space" used until the update installed.  I don't recall what exactly pushed the install over the edge and made it go, but it was painful enough that I'm not bothering with the latest update (its just a point release, despite the version number they're showing you its not an ICS update).

Comment: thanks for the clarification about the version (too bad: I was really looking forward to ICS, guess I'll just use CMod or something).  As for the whole cache partition wipe, I'll let you know if that works (I didn't realize until now that I actually have a lot of free space, and that the low space notification is actually a glitch).

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed a custom recovery (Clockwork or other) you won't be able to install the OTA update. You have to be stock ROM, with stock recovery in order to install OTA updates.

I am assuming that you have rooted and installed a custom recovery since you listed rom-manager as a tag.

If you want the update you will first have to get back to stock recovery and rom. Your best bet at this point is to install a custom ROM that was built from the latest update. That should stop Verizon pushing the update to your device.

Comment: I have not rooted (yet) nor installed a custom ROM.  Where can I find an original, factory ROM from Google?

Comment: You could look at the XDA forums for ROMs. I'm sure the factory image is available there somewhere: http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=635 If you have not rooted your phone and aren't using rom-manager, you should remove that tag from your post.