# Cannot install some apps in Android 4.1.2

Tags: applications, installation, insufficient-memory

I have a Motorola Razr D3 cellphone. Although I have at the moment 800 megabytes free on the device memory, some apps report insufficient space to perform the installation. I've cleaned caches and removed many apps.

I'm unable to install some software, for example, [Aircrack-ng](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/).

[image: Storage space]

What should I check for?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Insufficient storage" when trying to install new app](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23010/insufficient-storage-when-trying-to-install-new-app)

Comment: First check *where exactly* you have *how much* space free. Storage is divided into multiple locations, such as device storage, internal, and external SDCard (depending on what's available). The "insufficient space" error always refers to *device storage*, not to any of the SDCards. If your device storage gets low, it doesn't help to have plenty of space elsewhere. See our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) for details and first aid.

Comment: I have 800mb free in the internal memory. The SD card I have has 32 gb and only about 1gb used. So I do have free space on the right place.

Comment: See also: [“Low on space” warning with over 50% free](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/15666/16575) / [Google Play: Error downloading app - insufficient space](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/27083/16575) / [False “low on space” (internal storage) warning on HTC Incredible](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/21300/16575)

Comment: I fixed it formating the device. Still this not a solution.